# Take $f(x)$ to be an arbitrary function on $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=c \not = 0$ therefore $f(x)$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=c \not = 0$.

To show that $f(x)$ necessarily diverges, I was told it follows from [the limit test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitTest.html). That is as if to say:
$\sum_{x \in [1,\infty)\subset\mathbb{Z}} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$ implies that $f(x)$ will also diverge. Is there a proof or some intuition about this one may offer?

Comment: What is $x$ here? Real or Integer? Not clear from your notations.

Comment: My bad. Assume $x$ to be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really seem to make much difference that we restrict

$x \in \Bbb Z, \tag 1$

for if

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = c \ne 0, \tag 2$

then by definition, given any

$\epsilon > 0, \tag 3$

there exists

$M > 0 \tag 4$

such that

$x > M \Longrightarrow \left \vert \dfrac{f(x)}{x} - c \right \vert < \epsilon; \tag 5$

that is,

$-\epsilon < \dfrac{f(x)}{x} - c < \epsilon, \tag 6$

or

$-\epsilon x < f(x) - cx < \epsilon x, \tag 7$

whence

$(c - \epsilon)x < f(x) < (c + \epsilon)x; \tag 8$

now if

$c > 0 \tag 9$

we choose

$\epsilon < \dfrac{c}{2}; \tag{10}$

then

$c - \epsilon > \dfrac{c}{2} > 0, \tag{11}$

and it follows that

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \left ( c - \epsilon \right ) x = \infty, \tag{12}$

whence (8) implies

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty \tag{13}$

as well; on the other hand, with

$c < 0, \tag{14}$

we choose

$0 < \epsilon < -\dfrac{c}{2}; \tag{15}$

now

$c + \epsilon < -\dfrac{c}{2}, \tag{16}$

whence

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (c + \epsilon)x = -\infty, \tag{17}$

and (8) yields

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -\infty; \tag{18}$

we see that $f(x)$ diverges for all $c \ne 0$.

Comment: The only reason I restricted the sequence was due to a specific application though your proof still of course applies to my problem.

Comment: @BayesIsBae:  Well, $x \in \Bbb Z$ or $x \in \Bbb R$, as you say the proofs are essentially the same.  Thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, since $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=c\neq 0,$$ then there is some $N$ such that, for all $x\ge N,$ we have $$\left|\frac{f(x)}x-c\right|<|c|.$$ From this, it follows that there is some $d>0$ such that

1. $\frac{f(x)}x\ge d$ whenever $x\ge N,$ or
2. $\frac{f(x)}x\le -d$ whenever $x\ge N.$

Consequently, we have for all $n>N$ that $$\left|\sum_{x\in[N,n]\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x\right|=\sum_{x\in[N,n]\cap\Bbb Z}\left|\frac{f(x)}x\right|=\sum_{x\in[N,n]\cap\Bbb Z}d=(n-N)d.$$

Thus, $$\left|\sum_{x\in[N,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{x\in[N,n]\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-N)d=\infty.$$

Since one of the facts 1 or 2 must hold, this means that either $$\sum_{x\in[N,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x=\infty$$ or $$\sum_{x\in[N,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x=-\infty.$$ In either case, $$\sum_{x\in[1,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x$$ diverges, as desired.

Comment: I am failing to see how this implies $f(x)$ divergence, exactly.

Comment: This is because $$\sum_{x\in[1,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x=\sum_{x\in[1,N)\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x+\sum_{x\in[N,\infty)\cap\Bbb Z}\frac{f(x)}x.$$

Comment: If there are any steps in my proof outline that you didn't follow (or simply want to have your reasoning confirmed), please let me know. Welcome to Math.SE!

Answer (score 0):

Since $c\neq 0$ and $f(x) /x\to c$ as $x\to\infty $, it follows that $f(x) /x$ (and therefore $f(x) $) maintains same sign as $c$ and $|f(x) | > (|c|/2)x$ for large $x$. It follows that $f(x) \to\infty $ or $f(x) \to-\infty $ as $x\to\infty $ depending on whether $c>0$ or $c<0$.